# Setting Decimal places with normalized number by Series.value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to get percentage of my data.

```
    counts  
Win                         
BLUE 90729  
RED  86010
```

I used `df['counts'].value_counts(normalize = True)`
and it returns

```
86010    0.5
90729    0.5
Name: matchid, dtype: float64
```

how can i calculate them up to at least 2 decimal places?

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the percentage counts of BLUE/(BLUE+RED), etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the counts by their sum:

```
df['counts'] / df['counts'].sum()
#       counts
#Win          
#BLUE  0.51335
#RED   0.48665
```

In your original solution, there is *one* instance of 90729 and *one* instance of 86010. That is why `value_counts` returns 1 for 90729 and 1 for 86010 (after normalization, both become precisely 0.5).

Comment: Nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
df['perc'] = df['counts'].apply(lambda x: x/np.sum(df['counts']))
```

Output:

```
BLUE    0.51335
RED     0.48665
```